# boost::thread passing data between threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, boost

I am attempting to pass data between two sub classes of my main threading class using boost::thread. I am very new to multithreading and in a bit over my head.  Right now the code produces the following repeatedly.

```
Reader Api: 0
```

Below is my class andd subclass definitions. The threading class is a singleton.

```
class threading
{
public:
    static threading *Instance();
    void workerFunc();
    void workerFunc2();
    void inputWorkerFunc();  // handles input processing

    void producer();
    void consumer();


    int getGlobalVariable()  // retrieves the value of globalVariable
    {
        return (globalVariable);
    } 
    void setGlobalVariable(int set) // sets the value of globalVariable 
    {
        globalVariable = set;
    }

    class Reader   
    {
        public:
        Reader(int waitTime) { _waitTime = waitTime;}
        void operator() () 
        {
            threading *thread = threading::Instance();
            int globalVariable = thread->getGlobalVariable();
            for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) 
            {
                logMsg("Reader Api: " +Ogre::StringConverter::toString(globalVariable));
//       usleep(_waitTime);
                boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::microseconds(_waitTime));
            }
            return;
        }
    private:
        int _waitTime;
    };


    class Writer
    {
        public:
            Writer(int variable, int waitTime)
            {
                _writerVariable = variable;
                logMsg("Writer Variable: " +Ogre::StringConverter::toString(_writerVariable));

                _waitTime = waitTime;
            }
            void operator () () 
            {
                logMsg("Writer Variable: " +Ogre::StringConverter::toString(_writerVariable));

                threading *thread = threading::Instance();
                int globalVariable = thread->getGlobalVariable();
                for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) 
                {
//        usleep(_waitTime);
                    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::microseconds(_waitTime));
                    logMsg("Waittime Variable: " +Ogre::StringConverter::toString(_waitTime));

                    // Take lock and modify the global variable
                    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(_writerMutex);
                    globalVariable = _writerVariable;
                    thread->setGlobalVariable(globalVariable);

                    _writerVariable++;
                    // since we have used scoped lock, 
                    // it automatically unlocks on going out of scope
                }   
                logMsg("Writer Variable: " +Ogre::StringConverter::toString(_writerVariable));
//                    thread->setGlobalVariable(globalVariable);
            }   
        private:
            int _writerVariable;
            int _waitTime;
            static boost::mutex _writerMutex;
    };

protected:
    threading();
    threading(const threading&);
    threading& operator= (const threading&); 
private:
    static threading *pInstance;       
int globalVariable; 
    boost::mutex mutex;
    boost::condition_variable condvar;
    typedef boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lockType;
    double value;
    int count;
 };
```

Here is how I am calling the classes in my main code:

```
threading *thread = threading::Instance();
threading::Reader reads(100);
threading::Writer writes1(100, 200);
threading::Writer writes2(200, 200);

boost::thread readerThread(reads);
boost::thread writerThread1(writes1);
boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::microseconds(100));

boost::thread writerThread2(writes2);

readerThread.join();
writerThread1.join();
writerThread2.join();
```

Comment: You should have a mutex in the context of the data (here a global_mutex) not in the context of a reader or writer (as you do). Please lock that mutex in the reader, too

Answer (score 1):

You're obviously missing a decent synchronization mechanism like a (global) mutex, to prevent race conditions with this code:

```
static std::mutex globalVariableProtector;

int getGlobalVariable()  // retrieves the value of globalVariable
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(globalVariableProtector);
    return (globalVariable);
} 
void setGlobalVariable(int set) // sets the value of globalVariable 
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(globalVariableProtector);
    globalVariable = set;
}
```

Moreover, you actually should consider to place that variable into the producer thread's class, and provide getter/setter functions for it, instead of using a global variable.

---

I've been sharing the [current standard references](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard), rather `boost`. Boost may have their own mechanisms of `lock_guards` and [Synchronized Data Structures](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/thread/sds.html), if you for reason can't use the current c++ standard.

Comment: @MikeMcLean Please don't post any additional code in comments. May be the better choice is to ask a new question, describing exactly what  _troubles_ you've got with your adapted code. Don't forget to provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with your new question.